# No visible results, can anyone help?

Tags: muscle, protein, supplements, whey

I’m 16 years old. I’ve been using gold whey protein for quite some time now n frankly I'm seeing no results so I was thinking of switching to inner armor hard mass gainer..think it's a good idea? And also I think whey irritates my acne too so does hard mass container whey too? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What else are you doing? If you're just using a protein supplement, but not strength training, or eating for your goals (eating extra to gain weight or less to lose weight), then a protein supplement is unlikely to have any effect for you other than to support your overall health. Also as it stands, this questions is solely focused on nutrition which is considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: What's your workout plan? What's your daily calorie intake like?

Comment: What do you mean by "quite some time"? If you're expecting visible results after just a few months, you're mistaken.

Comment: Eat. Lift. Eat some more. Repeat many times. See results.

Answer (score 0):

Whey gold standard (Optimum Nutrition) is protein. What it does is giving nutrients to your muscles to recover properly (among several other things). Mass gainers are based on carbohydrates, which provide your blood with glucose, the "fuel" of your muscles. If it is not used, it becomes fat.
So, if you want to gain clean mass, better use whey, but if you are bulking and you don't mind about some fat because you are planning a cutting routine in the future, use a mass gainer.

By the other hand, when you say you don't see any results, you have to know some things:
1- Dietary supplements are a help, not a miracle.
2- Workout hard to your limit with good execution and good routine is the basis of progress.
3- There is nothing that supplements can do if you are eating wrong (wrong ingredients, wrong quantity or wrong timing)
4- Supplements are not steroids. You won't gain in 3 months what you would gain in 6 without them. I would say that using whey increases your progress speed by 10% or 20%, depending on many factors.

In conclusion, assuming your diet, routine and routine execution are at least correct, i would recommend you to take 30g of whey just after training, and at least 30g more before bed (at least on training days). If you want, you can take 10-15g before training also, but it is not so important. These amounts can increase if you are an intermediate level.

EDIT: what I said about what proteins and carbs do might be slightly inaccurate. I just gave a simplified explaination.